# How to effectively distribute break glass accounts for cloud access?

Tags: passwords, cloud, break, aero-glass

This issue came up for my organization recently.
In the case of extreme emergency a method is needed to effectively ensure that designated individuals can 'break glass' and enable access to a locked out cloud tenant / instance.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my proposed solution.
Even if any 2 of the designated admins are absent, a break glass re-entry is possible.
[image: Break Glass Password Distribution Model]